# Windows phone 8 Multiple Grids in Pivot Page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gridview, windows-phone-8, grid

I want to create pivot page with best scores for three different map sizes but I cant add anything to my grids, here is code :

```
    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="Piwne memory">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="4x5" Name="pivot1">
            <Grid x:Name="firstGrid"></Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="5x6" Name="pivot2">
            <Grid x:Name="secondGrid"></Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <!--Pivot item three-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="6x6" Name="pivot3">
            <Grid x:Name="thirdGrid"></Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

And my .cs file which generates grid's :

```
 private void createGrid()
    {
        int size = BestScore.BestScoreListLenght;
        int k = 4;
        textBlockArray = new TextBlock[size, k];

        this.firstGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        this.secondGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        this.thirdGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        for (int rows = 0; rows < size; rows++)
        {
            RowDefinition gridRow = new RowDefinition();
            gridRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            this.firstGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
            gridRow = new RowDefinition();
            gridRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            this.secondGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
            gridRow = new RowDefinition();
            gridRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            this.thirdGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
            for (int columns = 0; columns < k; columns++)
            {
                if (rows == 0)
                { // We only create columns in first loop.
                    ColumnDefinition gridColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                    gridColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                    if (columns == 0)
                        gridColumn.Width = new GridLength(35);
                    this.firstGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColumn);

                    gridColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                    gridColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                    if (columns == 0)
                        gridColumn.Width = new GridLength(35);
                    this.secondGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColumn);

                    gridColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                    gridColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                    if (columns == 0)
                        gridColumn.Width = new GridLength(35);
                    this.thirdGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColumn);
                }

                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                if (columns == 1)
                    tb.Text = (rows + 1).ToString();
                else
                    tb.Text = "";
                textBlockArray[rows,columns] = tb;

                //firstGrid.Children.Add(textBlockArray[rows,columns]);

                //Grid.SetRow(textBlockArray[rows, columns], rows);
                //Grid.SetColumn(textBlockArray[rows, columns], columns);


            }
        }
    }
```

This creates grids for all 3 pages but i cant add any text block to them..
Can any one help me with this one ? Im stuck with this for hours now :/

Comment: You should populate even the other columns

Comment: To better test your logic use TextBox instead TextBlock just temporary until you define your logic then go back to textblock

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! 
Finally found right answer at :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/1807fd62-26d1-495b-b772-d899a2a81b59/dynamically-adding-images-in-grid?forum=wpdevelop

I had to do something like this :

```
                tb.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columns);
                tb.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rows);
                textBlockArray[rows, columns] = tb;
                firstGrid.Children.Add(tb);
```

and it all worked out :)